# $ {I} and ${colours[i]} is not printing the values in console?

Tags: javascript, console

```
const colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
for(let i=0, max = colors.length; i< max; i++)
{
console.log('Color at position ${i} is ${colors[i]}');
}
```

output: Color at position ${i} is ${colors[i]}

Comment: As far as I know you want the back-tick. ` Color at position ${i} is ${colors[i]} `.

Comment: How would JS find your variables from a regular string. You maybe wanted to use a template literal string instead ..?

Answer (score 1):

string interpolation using backticks `` (the key commonly besides number 1 on your keyboard)

```
const colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
for(let i=0, max = colors.length; i< max; i++)
{
  console.log(`Color at position ${i} is ${colors[i]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
const colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
for(let i=0, max = colors.length; i< max; i++)
{
console.log('Color at position '+ i + ' is '  + colors[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the same....but there I got a example in a tutorial where it is mentioned in all the examples ${var_name} with a proper output... but am not able to get it...